# Unable to pass parameter to struts2 action from <s:action> tag

Tags: java, struts2

I am developing a web application with struts2. Here i am getting orders list by calling action by action tag. Now I want to send current date to Action class. I used param tag under action tag.. But I am not getting this parameter in Action class over request scope.

```
<s:action var="bkngorder" name="getBookingorderDeatils" ignoreContextParams="true" 
        executeResult="true"> 
    <s:param name="foo" value="bar"/> 
</s:action>
```

Comment: <s:action var="bkngorder" name="getBookingorderDeatils" ignoreContextParams="true" executeResult="true">
         <s:param name="foo" value="bar"/>
   </s:action>

Comment: this is the code i am using

Comment: Why do you use `ignoreContextParams="true" `?

Comment: Actually i dont know use of ignoreContextParams. I got it somewhere. Now i removed it. Still it isnt working

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?